# React Navigation header onPress - this.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using react-navigation in my project and I need to toggle a modal on right header button click. When I setState to true, I get undefined.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { ToggleDrawer, ToggleAdditional } from '../../utils';
import { AdditionalModal } from '../../components';

class Settings extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
    return {
      headerTitle: 'Profile',
      headerLeft: <ToggleDrawer pressHandler={() => navigation.openDrawer()} />,
      headerRight: (
        <ToggleAdditional pressHandler={() => params.handleAdditionalModal()} />
      )
    };
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      modalIsVisible: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    navigation.setParams({
      handleAdditionalModal: this.toggleAdditionalModal
    });
  }

  toggleAdditionalModal() {
    this.setState({
      modalIsVisible: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { modalIsVisible } = this.state;

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Settings</Text>
        <AdditionalModal isVisible={modalIsVisible} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Settings;
```

What am I doing wrong and what's the best way to handle such click events in react-navigation header?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to bind the `this` context to `toggleAdditionalModal ` or write it as an arrow function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try using arrow function for `toggleAdditionalModal`

```
 toggleAdditionalModal = () =>{
    this.setState({
      modalIsVisible: true
    });
  }
```

you need arrow function because you want to access `this` property, which refers to the current class.

Arrow functions means that `this` will not refer  to the context of your function but to the context of the class.

Comment: Thanks! It works) The problem is in arrow function this binding?

Comment: @drevival exactly :) consider marking it a correct answer, if it worked for you

Comment: Sure, I will. Have to wait for 10 minutes due to StackOverflow rules